# ILogger GetCurrentClassLogger in ActionFilterAttribute only works with usage in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog, actionfilterattribute

I would like to log the body for some requests in my API and have created an `ActionFilterAttribute` for this purpose. Therefore, I created a simple `TypeFilterAttribute` which calls my `ActionFilterAttribute` in it. Locally everything works fine, but when I deploy it nothing is logged unless I call the `ILogger` once in the constructor. Correct, I need to use the `ILogger` once in the `RequestLoggerService` in the constructor, then everything works.

**Why do I need to call the `ILogger` in the constructor for logging to work?**

I deliberately do not want to use the `ILogger` as a static variable like:

```cs
private static readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

The reason is the simplified overloading of the `ILogger` in UnitTests.

Simplified, my code looks like this:

Example of controller:

```cs
[NoAuthorization]
[HttpPost("response")]
[RequestLogger(true, true)]
public IActionResult PostResponse([FromBody] StringRequestModel model)
{
    return Ok($"Received Message: '{model.Message}' at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString()} - {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()} UTC");
}
```

My `RequestLoggerAttribute`:

```cs
public class RequestLoggerAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RequestLoggerAttribute(bool logBody = false, bool logHeader = false) : base(typeof(RequestLoggerService))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { logBody, logHeader };
    }
}
```

My `RequestLoggerService`:

```cs
public class RequestLoggerService : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly bool _logHeader;

    private readonly bool _logBody;

    public ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public RequestLoggerService(bool logBody, bool logHeader)
    {
        _logHeader = logHeader;
        _logBody = logBody;
        // Why do I need this line?
        _logger.Info($"{nameof(RequestLoggerService)} called.");
    }

    public override async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
      // log HttpContext header
      _logger.Info($"requestHeaders: {requestHeadersText}");
      // log HttpContext body
      _logger.Info($"requestBody: {requestBodyText}");
    }
}
```

Comment: We use custom logging for WebApi in a full .Net Framework v4.8 MVC and WebAPI app, but we didn't want to annotate every webApi class, instead we just added the filter in WebApiConfig.cs as config.Filters.Add(new LogApi()) where LogApi is the name of our class that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute. Now all calls to ANY webApi actions hit the log method.

Comment: If I want to log every request I can also use a central middleware. The article asks why the `ILogger` has to be used once in the controller. If it is not called, there is no logging in `OnResultExecutionAsync`. Locally everything works, but not in the rolled out state, this I do not understand.

Comment: I think this has to due with the logger name. Please try with `public ILogger _logger =LogManager.GetLogger("myName");`

Comment: @Julian Good idea, unfortunately this did not work :(

Comment: Please share your config